# jQuery mobile content being covered by footer and header and footer don't stay fixed on scroll

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, blackberry

My problem is two fold. The first is that the footer blocks some of the content, the submit button as seen in the image. If I remove the  tags then it's fine. The second issue is that if scrolling down, or up too much the header and footer doesn't stay fixed. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="landing">
  <div data-role="header"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px"> </div>
    <div id="info"> </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="actionbar"> <a id="help" data-role="tab"> <img src="img/ic_help.png"/>
      <p>Help</p>
      </a> <a id="chat" data-role="tab"> <img src="img/ic_textmessage.png"/>
      <p>Chat</p>
      </a> <a id="add" data-role="tab" href="#add"> <img src="img/ic_add.png"/>
      <p>Add </p>
      </a> <a id="settings" data-role="tab" href="#register"> <img src="img/Core_applicationmenu_icon_settings.png" alt="" />
      <p>Settings</p>
      </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="register">
  <div data-role="header"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="BB10Container">
      <form id="adduser">
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="John"/>
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Doe"/>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <label for="basic">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <label for="verpass">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="verpass" id="verpass" placeholder="Password"/>
        <label for="regemail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@email.com"/>
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" value="Submit" id="regsubmit">
</form>

    </div>
    <div id="info"> </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="actionbar"> <a id="help" data-role="tab"> <img src="img/ic_help.png"/>
      <p>Help</p>
      </a> <a id="chat" data-role="tab"> <img src="img/ic_textmessage.png"/>
      <p>Chat</p>
      </a> <a id="add" data-role="tab" href="#add"> <img src="img/ic_add.png"/>
      <p>Add </p>
      </a> <a id="settings" data-role="tab" href="#settings"> <img src="img/Core_applicationmenu_icon_settings.png" alt="" />
      <p>Settings</p>
      </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me out by pointing out my form height was probably 100%, which it was. Decreasing the height fixed this.